# Trying to proxy with Node and express-http-proxy and failing

Tags: node.js, express, npm, http-proxy

I'm launching NPM express in a very simple app and wanting to take what is passed into the URL and redirect it as follows. Assuming I'm listening for web traffic on 8080 and I want to proxy my rest calls to port 5000.

That is, when the URL http://localhost:3077/rest/speakers comes in, I want the results to come from http://localhost:5000/rest/speakers (where the word speakers could be sessions, attendees or any other name like that.

```
app = express();
app.use('/rest', proxy('http://localhost:5000/rest'));

app.listen(8080, function () {
  console.log('Listening on port 8080');
});
```

I seem to get the result of localhost:5000 but not even sure of that.

Comment: I've figured this out by using http-proxy-middleware instead. I'll post answer when the SO timer allows me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to using http-proxy-middleware and this solved my problem.

```
app = express();
const proxy = require("http-proxy-middleware");
const targetVal = 'http://localhost:5000/rest';
app.use(proxy('/rest', {target: process.env.DEV_RESTURL, changeOrigin:true}));
```